# Galerkin method for initial-boundary value problem

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem, galerkin-methods

Consider to 
     $$u_{t}(x,t)=u_{xx}(x,t)$$
$$u(0,t)=u(1,t)=0$$
$$u(x,0)=f(x)$$
I want to solve this problem by the Galerkin method based on finite dimensional space $X_{N}$, please help me. Providing that all test functions satisfies boundary conditions, i.e.

$$X_{N}:=span\lbrace\phi_{0}(x),...,\phi_{n}(x)\rbrace$$
$$\phi_{i}(0)=0, \phi_{i}(1)=0,$$
for all $i=0..N$

thanks

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to do that...the solution is just the zero function.

Comment: Excuse me, I edit my question. the initial condition is f(x).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the (Faedo-)Galerkin method aims to solve the weak formulation of the problem. In your case, this is given by the following: given $f\in L^2(0,1)$, find $u\in L^2(0,T;V)$ such that

$$
_{V^*}\langle u_t,v\rangle_V+(\nabla u, \nabla v)_0=0
$$
and $u(x,0)=f(x)$, where $V=H^1_0(0,1)$ and $V^*=H^{-1}(0,1)$, $_{V^*}\langle u_t,v\rangle_V$ is the duality pairing between $V^*$ and $V$, and $(\cdot,\cdot)_0$ is the inner product in $L^2(0,1)$. Incidentally, the equation above can be written in the more friendly form

$$
\frac{d}{dt}(u,v)_0 + (\nabla u,\nabla v)_0=0.
$$

The Faedo-Galerkin method aims to find a solution of the form

$$
u(x,t)=\sum_{j=0}^n c_j(t)\phi_j(x).
$$
If we plug this expression into the equation, and using linearity, we find that the vector $\underline{c}(t)$ of coefficients $c_j(t)$ must solve

$$
M\underline{\dot{c}}(t)+A\underline{c}(t)=\underline{0}
$$
with initial condition $\underline{c}(0)=\underline{f}$ and we defined the matrices $M,A$ and the vector $\underline{f}$ as

$$
M_{i,j}=(\phi_i,\phi_j)_0,\quad A_{i,j}=(\nabla \phi_j,\nabla \phi_i)_0\quad f_i=(f,\phi_i)_0.
$$

Now, once you fix the choice of your basis $\phi_0(x),\ldots,\phi_n(x)$, you can compute the matrices $A,M$ and the vector $\underline{f}$. All you have to do now is solve the Cauchy problem

$$
\begin{cases}
M\dot{\underline{c}}(t) = -A\underline{c}(t)\\
\underline{c}(0)=\underline{f}.
\end{cases}
$$
You can do this numerically, or, for particular choices of the basis, you may be able to compute an analytical solution (which may be complicated).

Note: here we did not discuss the convergence property of the method as $n\to \infty$, a topic which involves quite a bit of functional analysis. Instead, we only focused on how to compute a finite dimensional approximation to the solution (although, to be fair, you should only call it an *approximation* once you know that there is a convergence theorem in the background). Nevertheless, to make sure you are doing something meaningful, you should choose as basis the first $n$ elements of a basis of $V$. Notice that, if they are orthogonal in $V$ and in $L^2(0,1)$, then the system decouples into $n$ independent ODE's. If your basis is not orthonormal, the system still works, and you can diagonalize $A$ with respect to $M$ to obtain $n$ independent ODE's.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your respose....